# Setting a slower zoom speed

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

Is it possible to set a slower zoom speed? I'm using setView to transition between points of interest on a map and would like to use a slower transition. I haven't been able to find a way to set a slower zoom in/out speed anywhere in the documentation, and setting pan duration option doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

> Increase the transition time in the css for : ".leaflet-zoom-anim 
>   .leaflet-zoom-animated {"

From

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/leaflet-js/tQON0zgwZiE

Comment: Thank you. However, is there a way to do it only with my specific setView calls, rather than globally?

Comment: Copy-pasting from a Google search doesn't help much, especially if someone doesn't know what "transition time" is. Can you give a CSS example for other users who might need this answer?